# How to remap a touch to another window?

Tags: ios, uiresponder

I have an iPad with an external touchscreen. I am trying to remap the coordinate system of the external touchscreen to the `UIWindow` that is shown there.

I am getting the touches on the `UIViewController` of the `UIWindow` that is displayed on the iPad, as if I was touching the iPad. I do get them with the touchtype `.stylus`, which is how I can distinguish them from actual iPad touches (I will show different views on the iPad and the external screen). I am using the following code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchesOnExternalWindow = touches.filter({ $0.type == .stylus })
    let touchesOnIpad = touches.subtracting(touchesOnExternalWindow)
    if !touchesOnIpad.isEmpty {
        super.touchesBegan(touchesOnIpad, with: event)
    }

    if !touchesOnExternalWindow.isEmpty {
        guard let externalWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.screen.bounds == screenBounds }) else {
            fatalError("Touching the external display without an external display is not supported!")
        }

        externalWindow.rootViewController?.view.touchesBegan(touchesOnExternalWindow, with: event)
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass the touches along to the second `UIWindow`, as if I were touching there. But that does not seem to work.

How can I touch a view programmatically? I am testing now with a button on the second screen, but it will need to work with SceneKit views as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could have only one first responder at time and it can pass events only to one next responder.
So if you want to handle touches with stilus in external window, you need place this code inside into your iPad UIViewController next responder (it's not clear who next responder of your iPad UIViewController).
In the next responder of iPad UIViewController you place this code:

```
override var next: UIResponder? {
    // The next responder of The UIResponder chain.
    // It will receive responder events (like touches)
    // that current responder (your iPad window UIViewController next reponder) did't handle.
    guard let externalWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.screen.bounds == screenBounds }) else { 
       fatalError("Touching the external display without an external display is not supported!")
     }
    return externalWindow
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchesOnExternalWindow = touches.filter({ $0.type == .stylus })
    let touchesOnIpad = touches.subtracting(touchesOnExternalWindow)
    if !touchesOnIpad.isEmpty {
        // Here you handle your touches on iPad, instead of passing it to next responder
    }

    // Pass touches to next responder(external window).
    if !touchesOnExternalWindow.isEmpty {
        super.touchesBegan(touchesOnExternalWindow, with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: You return `nil` in a method that does not return anything?

Comment: @vrwim I apologize for mistake. Instead of returning nil, we need forward call to super. I'm edited my answer.

Comment: @vrwim and i'm add final editions. As i understood you want to handle all events besides the stylus touch events (as you say you want to draw some views on your iPad), and pass stylus touches to external window. The problem is that you can't pass events to multiple next responders.
If you wan't to handle this touches, you need handle it in your current responder tochesBegan method (or maybe you wan't pass it somehow to another object), and after you done pass the styles touch events to your external window.